# Absolute vs relative path for file manipulations in Symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony

Up until now, i used to do all my file manipulations using absolute path with the kernel class to get the project root dir, like this:

```
$imageFolder =
    $this->kernel->getRootDir()
    . '/../assets/uploads/images/
;
```

But today i tried using only a relative path such as

```
$this->filesystem->mkdir('assets/uploads/images');
```

And it works. So i'm a little confused because usually in PHP, all files access are done relative to the current file executing the script. I guess Symfony works in a way that the relative path always starts from the project root dir, but are there exceptions where it is required to provide a full absolute path or can i safely remove all my kernel calls safely ?

Thanks

Comment: I hate relative paths, just saying. It's a pain when I steal a site and run it locally, then I have to setup vHosts and all that mess.

Comment: I'm not talking about http paths but paths in PHP script for file manipulations.

Comment: There are both pros and cons to both approaches. Generally speaking, if I have a service that writes/reads to disk I will provide the basePath as constructor argument. Then I can easily switch between relative and absolute path by changing my configuration. You might also want to consider abstracting the filesystem away using something like [Gaufrette](https://github.com/KnpLabs/Gaufrette) or [Flysystem](http://flysystem.thephpleague.com/docs/). Unfortunately, since this is an open question, I still have to vote to close as opinion-based.

Comment: Ok but in which case would you want to provide the base path? I don't think this is opinion based, i just want to know if i'm safe just passing a path relative to the app root or if this can lead to issues and in which cases?

Comment: In your service using the image folder you have constructor like this: `__construct(string $imageBasePath)` and in your services.yml you then create a parameter: `images_base_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/../assets/uploads/images'` or `assets/uploads/images` and pass this it to the service. Since your code only refers to `$imageBasePath . '/image.png'` you don't have to care about relative/absolute anymore. This way, when you notice the relative base path does not work all you have to do is change the configuration in your services.yml without having to search through the code.

Comment: Yes, i get the idea but my question is precisely in which case would the relative base path not work ? I want to keep my code as clean as simple as possible and avoid passing arguments or dependencies to my services and controllers as much as possible, so if Symfony doesn't need an absolute path to do it's operations (which seems to be the case based on what i've tried), i'd rather keep it simple. So, are there precise cases when assuming that Symfony will use the app root as a starting point for a relative path will lead to issues ?

Comment: This is not so much a Symfony issue, but related to how PHP works. Under the hood the Filesystem component just performs file operations. If these low-level functions receive relative paths, they are interpreted as being relative to the current working directory (what is returned by the `getcwd()` function). This means that if you change the directory on the command-line and then execute the Symfony `console` script to run your application, it is likely that your relative paths no longer work as expected.

Comment: @xabbuh I think you are wrong. Some of my scripts are console commands (stored in src/Command), other are EventListeners (in src/EventListener/Subdirectory), other are in controllers. In each of those scripts i use the same relative path ("assets/uploads") and it works. So either Symfony executes somehow all the scripts in the root directory or it rewrites those relative paths so that they match the current working directory (for example "../../../assets/uploads" when i'm in a command.

Comment: So i've tried the getcwd() command which i did not know. When running the application in a browser, it always returns the absolute path to the public folder. When inside a console command, it returns the root folder. It my case it works either ways because i've created symbolic links to my assets in my public folder.

Comment: The working directory is not the directory where your source code files are stored (if you need to know that at runtime you can use `__DIR__`). It's the directory from which the script is started (i.e. when you are on the command-line it's what you change using `cd`).